# How to redirect http to https in NGINX in existing nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, https, rhel7, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm on RHEL7.9 Linux. I have a server (IP `a.b.c.d`) serving a webApplicationA and using https in nginx and it's working accessible at `https://a.b.c.d`.

On that same machine (same IP, `a.b.c.d`) I have an AppImage running which is a DIFFERENT web application, webApplicationB serving map tiles accessible at `http://a.b.c.d:3650`.
WebApplicationA needs to load the map tiles from `http://a.b.c.d:3650`, that is from webApplicationB.

The only way I'm currently able to get this to work (loading `http://a.b.c.d:3650` inside webApplicationA) is by configuring Chrome to "*Allow insecure content*". This is not acceptable.

I'm not sure I'm able to access the innards of the AppImage to embed any SSL keys. How would I go about modifying the `nginx.conf` for webApplicationA to proxy to `http://a.b.c.d:3650`, such that the loaded map tiles from webApplicationB is using https? I've spent a week researching and trying various "`/location`" parameters "`rewrite`" lines in the `nginx.conf` file with no luck. The more I research and try the more I feel I'm just trying anything and everything just hoping it magically works at this point. Can someone please explain how this is done?

Here's my existing server block. What would I add or change?

```
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  mapperapp;
        rewrite /login / redirect;

        ssl_certificate      nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  nginx.key;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  60m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**:
I added the following server block to my existing nginx.conf, and then navigated to `https://a.b.c.d:4653` and it worked.

```
    server {
        listen 4653 ssl;
        server_name mapperapp;

        ssl_certificate      nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  nginx.key;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  60m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host mapperapp;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
          proxy_pass http://a.b.c.d:3650;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a server block for another port, such as 4653, so that this nginx instance can serve `https://a.b.c.d:3653`. Then let this new server block proxies to `http://a.b.c.d:3650`.

Back to your webApplicationA, links starting with `https://a.b.c.d:3653` can be used and browsers won't warn any more.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide an example of such a server block using port 4653. Above is my existing server block; I'm not sure what besides the port that I need to include.

Comment: Thanks. You gave me the path to pursue and I got it working. The nginx.conf configuration that worked is up above.